# how to make a post request

Tags: python, post

I want to make post method request to the form

```
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlDistrict" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlDistrict\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlDistrict" tabindex="2" style="width:205px; font-size: medium;">
    <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
    <option value="2">ಬಾಗಲಕೋಟೆ / BAGALKOT</option>
    <option value="21">ಬೃ.ಬೆ.ಮ.ಪಾ / BANGALORE</option>
    <option value="22">ಬೆಂಗಳೂರು ಗ್ರಾಮಾಂತರ / BANGALORE RURAL</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="1">ಬೆಳಗಾವಿ / BELGAUM</option>
    <option value="12">ಬಳ್ಳಾರಿ / BELLARY</option>
    <option value="5">ಬೀದರ್‌ / BIDAR</option>
    <option value="3">ವಿಜಾಪೂರ / BIJAPUR</option>
    <option value="29">ಚಾಮರಾಜನಗರ / CHAMARAJNAGAR</option>
    <option value="19">ಚಿಕ್ಕಬಳ್ಳಾಪುರ / CHIKKABALLAPUR</option>
    <option value="17">ಚಿಕ್ಕಮಗಳೂರು / CHIKMAGALUR</option>
    <option value="13">ಚಿತ್ರದುರ್ಗ / CHITRADURGA</option>
    <option value="26">ದಕ್ಷಿಣ ಕನ್ನಡ / DAKSHINA KANNADA</option>
    <option value="14">ದಾವಣಗೆರೆ / DAVANGERE</option>
    <option value="9">ಧಾರವಾಡ / DHARWAD</option>
    <option value="8">ಗದಗ / GADAG</option>
    <option value="4">ಗುಲಬರ್ಗಾ / GULBARGA</option>
    <option value="25">ಹಾಸನ / HASSAN</option>
    <option value="11">ಹಾವೇರಿ / HAVERI</option>
    <option value="27">ಕೊಡಗು / KODAGU</option>
    <option value="20">ಕೋಲಾರ / KOLAR</option>
    <option value="7">ಕೊಪ್ಪಳ / KOPPAL</option>
    <option value="24">ಮಂಡ್ಯ / MANDYA</option>
    <option value="28">ಮೈಸೂರು / MYSORE</option>
    <option value="6">ರಾಯಚೂರು / RAICHUR</option>
    <option value="23">ರಾಮನಗರಂ / RAMANAGARAM</option>
    <option value="15">ಶಿವಮೊಗ್ಗ / SHIMOGA</option>
    <option value="18">ತುಮಕೂರು / TUMKUR</option>
    <option value="16">ಉಡುಪಿ / UDUPI</option>
    <option value="10">ಉತ್ತರ ಕನ್ನಡ / UTTARA KANNADA</option>
    <option value="35">ಯಾದಗಿರಿ / YADGIR</option>

</select>
```

how to send value=2 from python to this form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [python-request](http://docs.python-requests.org) library.
As example (from the documentation):

```
>>> payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)
```

Comment: but what is the name should I use post request .see the first line of code it as name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlDistrict" which is not working .when try to do post method request .

Comment: I don't know why this thing happens. I just was suspect in some encoding problem but there is a far shot! Some more information would help.